# 'Some services are not able to be constructed 'Error while validating the service descriptor '

Tags: mongodb, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I am working on a .Net core web API integrated with MongoDB. When I tried to run the build it gave me the below issue.
'Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: TeapiocaMIC.Service.LoginService Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: TeapiocaMIC.Service.LoginService': Unable to resolve service for type 'DatabaseContext' while attempting to activate 'TeapiocaMIC.Service.LoginService'.)'

Below is the DBContxt

```
public class DatabaseContext
{
    private readonly IMongoDatabase _database;

    private static DatabaseContext _instance;

    private DatabaseContext(IDatabaseSettings settings, IMongoClient mongoClient)
    {
        _database = mongoClient.GetDatabase(TableNames.DbName);
    }

    public IMongoCollection<MenuModules> MenuModulesCollection => _database.GetCollection<MenuModules>(TableNames.MenuModules);
    public IMongoCollection<Login> LoginCollection => _database.GetCollection<Login>(TableNames.Login);
    public IMongoCollection<Users> UserCollection => _database.GetCollection<Users>(TableNames.Users);
    public IMongoCollection<Roles> RolesCollection => _database.GetCollection<Roles>(TableNames.Roles);
    public IMongoCollection<Store> StoresCollection => _database.GetCollection<Store>(TableNames.Store);
    public IMongoCollection<StoresUsers> StoreUsersCollection => _database.GetCollection<StoresUsers>(TableNames.StoreUsers);

    public static DatabaseContext GetInstance(IDatabaseSettings settings, IMongoClient mongoClient)
    {
        if (_instance == null)
        {
            _instance = new DatabaseContext(settings, mongoClient);
        }
        return _instance;
    }
}
```

Startup.cs

```
public class Startup
 {
     public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
     {
         IConfiguration configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
             .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
             .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
             .Build();

         var mongoDBSettings = configuration.GetSection("MongoDBSettings").Get<DatabaseSettings>();
         var client = new MongoClient(mongoDBSettings.ConnectionString);
         services.AddSingleton(client);
         //services.AddSingleton<DatabaseContext>();
         services.AddScoped<DatabaseContext>();
         services.AddScoped<IMongoDatabase>(provider =>
         {
             var mongoClient = provider.GetService<MongoClient>();
             return mongoClient.GetDatabase(mongoDBSettings.DatabaseName);
         });
     }
 }
```

Program.cs

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using MongoDB.Driver;
using TeapiocaMIC.Service;
using TeapiocaMIC.Settings;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("AllowAllOrigins",
        builder =>
        {
            builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                   .AllowAnyHeader()
                   .AllowAnyMethod();
        });
});

builder.Services.Configure<DatabaseSettings>(
    builder.Configuration.GetSection(nameof(DatabaseSettings)));

builder.Services.AddSingleton<IDatabaseSettings>(sp =>
    sp.GetRequiredService<IOptions<DatabaseSettings>>().Value);

builder.Services.AddSingleton<IMongoClient>(sp =>
    new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/Teapioca"));
builder.Services.AddScoped<DatabaseContext>();

builder.Services.AddScoped<LoginService>();
/*builder.Services.AddScoped<UserService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<StoresUsersService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<RolesService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<StoreService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<MenuModulesService>();*/

builder.Services.AddControllers();

// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

// CORS Configuration
app.UseCors("AllowAllOrigins");

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseAuthorization();

// Add Error Handling Middleware
app.UseExceptionHandler(errorApp =>
{
    errorApp.Run(async context =>
    {
        context.Response.StatusCode = 500;
        context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
        // Handle and log the error here
        await context.Response.WriteAsync("An error occurred. Please try again later.");
    });
});

app.MapControllers();
app.Run();
```

LoginService.cs

```
public class LoginService 
  {
      private readonly IMongoCollection<Login> _login;
      public LoginService(DatabaseContext databaseContext)
      {
          _login = databaseContext.LoginCollection;
      }

      public Login GetByUserNameAndPassword(string userName, string password)
      {
          return _login.Find(login => login.UserName == userName && login.Password == password).FirstOrDefault();
      }
  }
```

Comment: You are not registering the `DatabaseContext` in Program.cs. And I believe that you are using .NET 6 or above, and the Startup class is not useful. You should move the code in that registering services to DI in the `Startup` class to Program.cs.

Comment: @YongShun I registered the db context "builder.Services.AddScoped<DatabaseContext>();" in the Program.cs, but still getting the same issue.

Comment: Update your latest code in the question.

Comment: @YongShun Done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You DatabaseContext class doesn't have a suitable constructor

modify

```
private DatabaseContext(IDatabaseSettings settings, IMongoClient mongoClient)
    {
        .....
    }
```

to

```
public DatabaseContext(IDatabaseSettings settings, IMongoClient mongoClient)
    {
        .....
    }
```

Comment: It's worked. Thanks.